# Good programming habits with MVC and Controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, controller

With MVC architecture, it's a good habit to have the controllers complety separated?

I mean, supose a Country and a Client controller. The country controller, has a GetAllCountries Action.

It's a good idea to do a GetAllCountries When I'm in a view of the Client Controller?(Let's say I want a dropdownlist with all the countries in the edit of the client.)

Or It's better to Make another GetAllCountries in the Client controller?

Comment: What is your medium? Desktop applications, embedded systems or web applications?

Comment: Hi @teresko, my medium is web applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on your expected application grow direction you have two options. if you expect to have many different operations related to country, do the CountryController. if you don't expect it then do something like DictionaryController because you will probably have list of languages, payment types etc.

for sure don't store it in ClientController because:
* you will have many different places where you will need list of countries
* ClientController is the last place where other developer will be looking for code related to list of countries

Comment: Does it means that is good to have a controler, only with a method of getAll()?

Comment: is it ok to have one method in a class? yes. is it ok to have a method 'getAll'? probably not. i have to ask you what does 'getAll' mean. and the fact i have to ask means the name is wrong. use getAllDictionaryValues or getAllAcviteDictionaryValues or something like that